# Google App Maker - How to keep constant space between the label and input of a dropdown/textbox widget?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a field in a form with label/display name:

"I can confirm that this supply is not subject to restrictions under the Test Group, or be of a specialist nature, and as such require other checks that this method does not support."

I am using a dropdown widget with options Yes and No to display it.

[image]

I could wrap the label by trying below css.

```
     .app-AddRequest-Field15-Label {
            white-space: normal;
       }
```

But now the space between the input and label is very less. Even if I put a margin top to the input when in mobile view the label wraps even more and the space still remains very less/ both override.

[image]

[image]

Images with borders

Label border: black

Input border: Orange

[image]

[image]

I want to keep a constant space in all views. Please suggest.

Comment: Why don't you use a label widget with the label styling instead of using the dropdwon label?

Comment: @Morfinismo  I already have a lot of such dropdown fields in my form and other forms. If I change to independent label approach then it will be bit of rework for me.

Comment: @Morfinismo One more observation if this may help in getting a clue. I added border to the label and input  to see why this is happening and from that it appears as if label is occupying all the space in the drop down widget and the input is coming inside that.

Comment: Updated the question with new screenshots

Answer (score 1):

I mocked up a solution that works for up to four lines of data in a label. These are the steps you need to follow:

1.) In the global css, make sure you have the following lines:

```
.app-Dropdown-Label {
  white-space: normal;
}

.twoLinesLabel{  
  top: -15px !important;
}

.threeLinesLabel{  
  top: -30px !important;
}

.fourLinesLabel{  
  top: -45px !important;
}
```

2.) On any of the client scripts place the following:

```
function adjustLabel(widget){
  var label = widget.getElement().children[0];
  var ch = label.clientHeight;
  var lines =  Math.floor(ch / 15);
  switch(lines){
    case 2:
      label.classList.add("twoLinesLabel");
      break;
    case 3:
      label.classList.add("threeLinesLabel");
      break;
    case 4: 
      label.classList.add("fourLinesLabel");
      break;
  }
}
```

3.) On the **onAttach** event handler of any dropdwon you need this adjustment, place the following:

```
adjustLabel(widget);
```

The only problem with that approach is that in the UI you won't be able to see the necessary space your field requires so that it don't overflows with the previous field. So you'll have to preview the app and make adjustements accordingly.

Another way is to make sure that your CSS looks like this instead:

```
.app-Dropdown-Label {
  white-space: normal;
}

.twoLinesLabel label{  
  top: -15px !important;
}

.threeLinesLabel label{  
  top: -30px !important;
}

.fourLinesLabel label{  
  top: -45px !important;
}
```

Then on the **Display** category of the property editor, simply add the correspoding style to the dropdown. That way you will be able to see the changes in the editor immediately.

[image]

Whatever way you choose, the result is the following:

[image]

Comment: It worked up to an extent but still it needs us to do more adjustments and also some how it did not act on my forms which are in tab. Considering a direct straight forward solution not available ATM I shifted to individual label approach now as you mentioned earlier.

Comment: @ab.it.gcp Well, I tried my best. Good luck in the future implementations!